# AWS Cloudformation - Property validation failure: [Value of property {/RequestParameters/MessageAttributes} does not match type {String}]

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, aws-api-gateway

I have been trying to understand how to overcome the error:

```
Property validation failure: [Value of property {/RequestParameters/MessageAttributes} does not match type {String}]
```

The cloud formation resource in question is this:

```yaml
 HttpApiPayloadRouteIntegration:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref HttpApi
      Description: Proxy incoming HTTP Payload into SQS
      IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
      IntegrationSubtype: SQS-SendMessage
      PayloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
      CredentialsArn: !GetAtt HttpApiRole.Arn
      RequestParameters:
        QueueUrl: !Ref HTTPApiEventQueue
        MessageBody: $request.body
        MessageGroupId: $request.body.repository.full_name
        MessageDeduplicationId:
          !Join [
            "-",
            [$request.body.repository.full_name, $request.body.alert.number],
          ]
        MessageAttributes:
          - firstAttribute:
              DataType: String
              StringValue: hello world
          - secondAttribute:
              DataType: String
              StringValue: goodbye world
```

The error is happening here:

```yaml
        MessageAttributes:
          - firstAttribute:
              DataType: String
              StringValue: hello world
          - secondAttribute:
              DataType: String
              StringValue: goodbye world
```

I have tried:

```yaml
        MessageAttributes:
          firstAttribute:
              DataType: String
              StringValue: hello world
          secondAttribute:
              DataType: String
              StringValue: goodbye world
```

```yaml
        MessageAttributes:
          - firstAttribute:
              DataType: String
              StringValue: hello world
          - secondAttribute:
              DataType: String
              StringValue: goodbye world
```

```yaml
        MessageAttributes:
          firstAttribute:
              Name: firstAttribute
              Type: String
              Value: hello world
          secondAttribute:
              Name: secondAttribute
              Type: String
              Value: goodbye world
```

My question is really. How do you send MessageAttributes in a `yaml` cloud formation template?

Answer (score -1):

The AWS Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-integration.html) say that in YAML template the propertie `RequestParameters` is parsed like a JSON.

Here a YAML template example:

```
MyIntegration:
Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
Properties:
  ApiId: !Ref MyApi
  Description: HTTP proxy integration
  IntegrationType: HTTP_PROXY
  IntegrationMethod: ANY
  IntegrationUri: https://api.example.com
  PayloadFormatVersion: 1.0
  RequestParameters:
    "append:header.header1": "$context.requestId"
  ResponseParameters:
    "200":
      ResponseParameters:
        - Source: "headerValue"
          Destination: "append:header.header2"
```

An example with CLI:

```
aws apigatewayv2 create-integration \
    --api-id abcdef123 \
    --integration-subtype SQS-SendMessage \
    --integration-type AWS_PROXY \
    --payload-format-version 1.0 \
    --credentials-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/apigateway-sqs \
    --request-parameters '{"QueueUrl": "$request.header.queueUrl", "MessageBody": "$request.body.message"}'
```

Looks like `Request Parameters` all the time is mapped in JSON format